# posts_nav_link() isn't displaying more posts when link is clicked

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom template page in WordPress and I'm trying to get the post-listing pagination to work properly. I have used `posts_nav_link()` after the loop, and it does display the "Previous Page" and "Next Page" links, but when they are clicked it does not load any new posts. The URL shows that it is paging (by showing .../page/2 and .../page/3 etc...) but each page that is paged through still has the same 10 posts on it.

My code for the custom page template is:

```
<div class="content content-page">
    <main class="site-main">

        <?php
            $custom_loop = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type'      => 'post',
                'order'          => 'DESC',
                'orderby'        => 'date',
                'category_name' =>  'Arcology Podcast'
            ) );
        ?>

         <?php 
        // Start the Loop
        if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) { 
            while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) { 
                $custom_loop->the_post(); 
                // Include the page content
                get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
                ?>
                <hr/>
                <?php
            }
            next_posts_link("Older Entries", $custom_loop->max_num_pages);
            previous_posts_link("Newer Entries");
        }
        // End the Loop
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

    </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution to my problem, so I'm posting it here for the benefit of others:

The problem was that the `paged` parameter was not set in the `WP_Query` object, so the query didn't know which page of posts to be showing. It defaults to page 1, of course, so every time I clicked the "Older Entries" link, it would reload the page and get the default page defined by the `paged` parameter (i.e. the first page was being loaded every time).

The solution is to set the `paged` parameter in the `WP_Query` object. You can find out what current page you are on by calling `get_query_var('paged')`. So the solution looked like this:

```
<div class="content content-page">
    <main class="site-main">

        <?php
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

            $custom_loop = new WP_Query( array(
                'paged'         =>  $paged,
                'post_type'      => 'post',
                'order'          => 'DESC',
                'orderby'        => 'date',
                'category_name' =>  'Arcology Podcast'
            ) );
        ?>

        <?php 
        // Start the Loop
        if ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) { 
            while ( $custom_loop->have_posts() ) { 
                $custom_loop->the_post(); 
                // Include the page content
                get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
                ?>
                <hr/>
                <?php
            }
            next_posts_link("Older Entries", $custom_loop->max_num_pages);
            previous_posts_link("Newer Entries");
        }
        // End the Loop
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>

    </main>
</div>
```